# Powershell does not recognise Java as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: java, powershell

I cannot seem to get any java commands to work. I do have java installed on my machine and I do not know where to proceed from here. Here is the code that appears when I try to open a java application:

```
java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again. At line:1 char:1
+ java -Xmx7000m -jar \BaseX\BaseX.jar
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (java:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

[image: Scrrenshot of Powershell]

Comment: Have you set up your `JAVA` and `JAVA_HOME` system variables?

Comment: Does it work from cmd.exe? Is the directory where java.exe is located in your path?

Comment: @TA I have no clue how to

Comment: @OcasoProtal No it does not work there either. Says something about java not recognised as an internal or external command. Also I followed that post you mentioned and got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add java to your path.

If you are on windows search 'edit the system environmental variables'. Add the path to your java/bin folder (should be in program files if Java is installed) and append to the variable value under the variable name "Path"